# How to add class using jQuery when only some element is available on the page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In page if the table with the class controls is available then only I want to add CSS to a `div` like `overflow-y` visible. Using jQuery.

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="controls" >
</table>
<div style="overflow"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "available"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do a simply `if` check for elements matching the selector (the [`.length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/)), for example:

```
if($("table.controls").length) {
  $("div").css({ "overflow-y": "visible" });
}
```

Though...that `"div"` selector should be much more specific to what you're after.  If you actually want to *add* the `<div>` then it would look like this:

```
$("table.controls").after('<div style="overflow-y: visible;"></div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `length` property to see if a jQuery object contains any elements:

```
if ($('table.controls').length > 0) {
  $('div').css('overflow-y','visible');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $('table.controls').length ) {
  $('div[style=overflow]').css('overflow-y','visible');
}
```

Comment: You might not find anything using `div[style=overflow]`. As the style is invalid, the browser might remove it when the HTML code is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('.controls').addClassToDiv();
}

$.fn.addClassToDiv = function(){
  return this.each(function(){
    $(this).next('div').addClass('myStyles');
  });
}
```

You should really keep your styles in your stylesheets rather than adding inline styles, but adding/removing classes is easy. Jut define your new styles in your stylesheet.

The JS adds a jQuery plugin called addClassToDiv that is run on page load, where there’s an element with a class of 'controls' in the page.